# CPU->GPU transfer vs GPU->CPU transfer

Tags: gpu, cpu, transfer

I have been doing some experiments regarding measuring the latency of data transfer from
CPU->GPU and GPU->CPU. I found that CPU->GPU data transfer rate is almost twice as much compared to GPU->CPU transfer rate for a particular message size. Can anybody explain me why this is so?

Comment: btw, how much is the transfer speed you obtain in terms of Mb/sec?

Comment: Why did you use "latency" here?

Answer (score 4):

Since don't know the detail about your experiment, like what's CPU/GPU used, how to measure transfer rate, I just guess that,
data transfer from CPU->GPU, normally is through DMA. each time it can transfer a block bytes from system memory to graphic memory.
But data transfer from GPU->CPU, normally CPU is to read the graphic aperture memory which is mapped by PCI bus. CPU only can read the aperture memory in un-cacheable, strict order byte by byte, so it is slow.

Comment: wouldn't you also be able to use DMA from GPU to host memory?